# document.cookie is not showing 'non httponly' cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, session-cookies

I am setting a cookie in PHP code:

```
setcookie('auth_token', $this->JWT, time() + TOKEN_LIFETIME, $value["path"], $value["domain"], $secure, false);
```

here, `httponly` field is set to `false`.
It is creating cookie, but `document.cookie` is not returning this cookie value.

What may be reason of `document.cookie` not returning the cookie value?

Comment: Does the auth_token cookie show up if you check it from your browser? 
(DevTools --> Application --> Cookies for Chrome)

Comment: No it was not showing theer.

Comment: When I put a blank domain name for setcokie() function, cookie is getting in document.cookie. And it is showing in Application -> Cookies Tab

Comment: why is it so? Any Idea

Comment: That sounds pretty odd. What if you try it with dummy values? `setcookie('auth_token', 'jwt', time() + TOKEN_LIFETIME, "path", domain.com, $secure, false);`

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
setcookie($name = 'yogesh', $value = 'nayi', $expire = 0, $path = "", $domain = "", 
$secure = false, $httponly = false);

var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Javascript

```
<script>
   console.log(document.cookie);
</script>
```

output
$httponly = false
[image: $httponly = false]

$httponly = false
[image: $httponly = false]

$httponly = true
[image: $httponly = true]